# How to retrieve POST request body in Forgerock openam

Tags: java, forgerock

I have an app that sends a request to Forgerock OpenAM IDP. I can access the data sent to the server if the data is sent by a GET request. Following is the code which does that.

```java
@Override
    public Action process(TreeContext context) throws NodeProcessException {
        try {
            Map<String, List<String>> parameters = context.request.parameters;
            …
    }
```

My problem:

How do i get the data i sent via a POST request. I have tried using the HttpServletRequest object present inside context object (`context.request.servletRequest`), but i am unable to get any data. Any pointers on how to get data posted to this URL would be really helpful!

I am posting data to the URL `https://myserverurl.com/openam/XUI/`